# How to dynamically scale images while keeping the same spacing between images in CSS?

Tags: css

I have attached an image that shows what I am trying to achieve. 3 images next to each other with the same spacing. As window grows or shrinks the images follow accordingly while keeping the same spacing.

Everything I tried leads to the images becoming too large and stop following the space between each other.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.foodTitle {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.mainContent {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  height: 450px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.foodPicture {
  display: flex;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

div.foodPicture {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
}

img.mainPictures {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  image-rendering: auto;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  color: #001219;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  sans-serif;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainContent">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="foodPicture">
      <a href="./recipes/lasagna.html">
        <img class="mainPictures" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621510456681-2330135e5871?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
        <span class="caption">Lasagna</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

[What Mine Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twMLb.png)

[What I am Looking For](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZELFF.jpg)

Comment: You only have one image in your HTML... and the text is narrower than the image. Please add more examples with better illustration of the type of effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get that spacing between each column, the cleanest way would be to use grid. The grid gap is what controls the spacing between each column. I added a media query to show the responsive outcome.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2rem; /* Adjust the grid gap to adjust the spacing between the columns */
}

.foodPicture a {
    text-decoration : none;
}

.caption {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
}


/* screens smaller than 768px, the grid items will be stacked */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

}
```

```html
<section class="mainContent">

        <div class="container">
      
          <div class="foodPicture">
            <a href="./recipes/lasagna.html">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img class="mainPictures" src="https://fakeimg.pl/500x300">  
                  </div>
              <span class="caption">Lasagna</span>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="foodPicture">
            <a href="./recipes/lasagna.html">
                <div class="img-container">
                  <img class="mainPictures" src="https://fakeimg.pl/500x300">  
                </div>
              <span class="caption">Lasagna</span>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="foodPicture">
            <a href="./recipes/lasagna.html">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img class="mainPictures" src="https://fakeimg.pl/500x300">  
                  </div>
              <span class="caption">Lasagna</span>
            </a>
          </div>
    </section>
```